# Ensure builtin command is run under pathological circumstances

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Given a hostile environment such as:

```
for word in builtin command type unfunction declare set unset alias; do
    eval "$word(){ echo $word function; };  alias $word='echo $word alias'"
done
```

Is it possible to access a builtin command?  Eg, is it possible to do something like:

```
\command \builtin \type echo
```

and still see:

```
echo is a shell builtin
```

Is possible for a hostile (or locked-down) environment to be able to completely redefine things such that an underlying builtin, function or pathname could never be accessed?

Comment: `unalias builtin; unset -f builtin`? I don't think this environment is hostile *enough*.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I like your sense of evil, and have updated with `eval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Bash, if you enable [POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode):

> 14. Function names may not be the same as one of the POSIX special builtins.
> 15. POSIX special builtins are found before shell functions during command lookup.

Since `set` and `unset` are special builtins, you can get access to them via the POSIX mode, and then use those to get rid of the functions, and then use `\unalias` to get rid of the aliases:

```
$ for word in builtin command type  declare set unset unalias alias; do     eval "$word(){ echo $word function; };  alias $word='echo $word alias'"; done 
alias function
$ unalias  builtin command type unfunction declare set unset alias
unalias alias builtin command type unfunction declare set unset alias
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1
$ \unset -f builtin command type  declare set unset unalias alias
$ \unalias  builtin command type unfunction declare set unset alias
bash: unalias: unfunction: not found
bash: unalias: alias: not found

$ type -a builtin
builtin is a shell builtin
```

---

But I can't think of a way back from, say:

```
enable -n set unset builtin command type  declare unalias alias typeset enable shopt
```

(Without trying to start a new shell, which maybe disallowed in a restricted shell.)